# YT API - get data in realtime, looking for solution

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to get data (especially **subscriptions.list** and **superChatEvents.list**) in a more realtime manner?

**What we do currently:** we send request to endpoints every **X** seconds, and filter received data to get only the latest. We have **X** seconds delay, which isn't even close to realtime. Shortening **X** costs us too much quota, because we need to support a lot of users (lets say 50 000)

**What we would like to do is:**

- send only ore request which gets data from more than one youtube channel (not something that YT API supports)

or

- have WebSocket connection ([Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) doesn't support what we're interested in)

or

- ?

There is a service online doing that (ex. you connect YT channel with them, channel gets subscription, and they know it immediately, and they support far more than 50 000 users), but they aren't open-source. All I managed to peep out is an enigmatic xhr request to **https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_interaction?alt=json&key=[devKey]** but google doesn't help when I'm searching for details about that, like it wouldn't exists.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita I have edited the question. Hope it's more clear now!